# Test pagereference redirection to detail page

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, controller-extension, pagereference

I am writing a test for a method in CreateNewCase class. This method in CreateNewCase class creates a new case and redirects the page to the new case's detail page.:

```
 public PageReference createCase() {
  Case c = new Case(Status = 'New', Origin = 'Phone', Subject = 'This is a New Case Created',Last_Verified_by_User__c=UserInfo.getUserId(),Last_Verified_Date_Time__c = datetime.now(),ContactId = cnt.Id);
  Insert c;
  Pagereference ref = new PageReference('/' + c.Id);
  return ref;
 }
```

I tried to test like below. I checked how to use

```
Pagereference pageref=Page.Mypage;
Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
```

and though I need to set the parameter as `testcase.id`, however `Page.MyPage` does not exist in my code. how do I test the redirection to the case details page in that scenerio?

```
@isTest
static void testcreateCase(){
    CreateNewCase caseobject=new CreateNewCase(new ApexPages.StandardController (new Contact()));
    Case testcase=new Case(Status = 'New');
    insert testcase;

    PageReference resPg = caseobject.createCase();
 //   System.assertEquals(, resPg);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to use `Test.setCurrentPage()`. That is used to set the page context, to test methods that read values from the current page URL or query strings. Your test could be something like this:

```
@isTest
static void TestCreateCase () {
    Contact ct= new Contact (LastName = 'Test');
    insert ct;
    CreateNewCase caseobject=new CreateNewCase(new ApexPages.StandardController (ct));

    PageReference resPg = caseobject.createCase();

    List<Case> cases = [SELECT Id, ContactId FROM case];
    // Assert that 1 and only 1 case was created
    System.assertEquals (1, cases.size());
    Case cs = cases[0];
    // Assert that the pageReference redirects to the Case
    System.assertEquals (resPg.getUrl(), '/' + cs.Id);
    // Assert that the case was assigned to the right contact
    System.assertEquals (cs.ContactId, ct.Id);
}
```

Comment: Yeah there is (almost) no reason to ever call that method.

Comment: Only reason to call it would be to set parameters that are got by apexPages.currentParameters().get(xxxx); or when using controller.getId() or similar

Comment: This solution does not address the use case. If there is an error inserting the case the user will be give the ugly error page. While it addresses the need / lack of need to set page reference (which was not a problem even if it was there) it does not solve the issue as a DML error will fail irrespective of the test code provided.

Comment: @Eric But you can add parameters to the default `PageReference`. Without ever calling it you can call `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put(param, value)`.

Comment: I agree, there has to be a condition which I need to include where the case insert fails. I will be able to write a test for that as I got an idea now. :)

Comment: @AdrianLarson - Good point. but for sake or purity you would not be on the correct page :)

Comment: @Eric I would argue that for the sake of purity, you should focus on your primary concern (parameters) and ignore peripheral properties (url, etc). You don't care *which* `PageReference` has the parameters, only that it does, in fact, have them.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - Yea, it was just tongue in cheek

Comment: @Eric The question asks for "how do I test the redirection to the case details page in that scenerio?", which is what my solution covers. I would agree that testing a failing case would be a more complete test coverage. For instance, what would it happen if we delete `ct` before calling case creation? I suspect an exception would be thrown, and the code would need to handle it.

Comment: You are correct, I misinterpreted the "no redirection occurred' on the initial edit. My apologies

Comment: No worries, man